# Неадекатная реакция на Старт

Tags: windows, cmd

Фото:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Обнаружил, что на команду из верхнего окна вместо запуска нужной прогры открывается нижнее окно. Это глюк системы или программы?

Comment: `start C:\"Portable Programs"\"Texmaker 2.1"\texmaker.exe`, если не работает то сперва `cd C:\"Portable Programs"\"Texmaker 2.1"` и потом `start texmaker.exe`. Если вы пишите start и дальше всё в кавычках то эта команда воспринимается как `открыть новое окно cmd с заголовком <всё что в кавычках>`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

У вас в пути есть пробел, из за этого вы указывает его в кавычках, `start` предполагает наличие *заголовка окна*, которое указывается в кавычках. Что бы `start` понял что это путь к программе, следует указать пустую пару кавычек в начале команды:

```
start "" "путь к вашей программе"
```

Comment: Всем большое сыпасибо): оба совета помогли.