# Не выполняется команда Windows через Jenkins

Tags: cmd, powershell, jenkins

Создал Jenkins job, который должен через командную строку запускать программу. Добавил шаг сборки: "Выполнить команду Windows" и прописал там команду:
start 'C:\Program Files (x86)\HPE\bin\leanft.bat' start
Выполнение дженкин джоба зависает на выполнении этой команды пока не отвалится по тайм ауту. В чем может быть проблема?

Если выполнять эту команду вручную на машине под тем же пользователем, под которым на нее ходит Jenkins, то она выполняется успешно.
Jenkins стоит на виртуалке под Linux. Команда выполняется на ноде под управление Windows Server.

Comment: А зачем start перед и после bat'ника?

Comment: Первый start указывает на запуск файла. Вторым Start'ом обозначается именно запуск программы. В ней можно выполнять несколько команд, например аналогично записанной командой stop ее можно остановить.

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1018977/341547

Comment: Спасибо. Ошибка ушла.